# What is the tightest known bound on the reconstruction error in compressed sensing?

Tags: compressive-sensing

I am specifically thinking about the reconstruction error of L1-minimization from compressed measurements with noise.
I know a bound from (8) in [The restricted isometry property and its implications for compressed sensing](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RIP.pdf), but I was wondering if there is anything newer and or tighter that I am not aware of. Additionally, I would like to relate $\delta_{2s}$ to the size of e.g. a Gaussian measurement matrix. It seems I can do that from Lemma 3.1 and (3.22) in [Decoding by linear programming](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/DecodingLP.pdf), but how tight is (3.22) and can I get closer?

Answer (score 5):

According to Michael McCoy on [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/e/1pftv1-h84ydu4f-2v/vaq/172754620/683737/98766203/view_disc/?hs=false&tok=06TM_7g1tHj5s1):

The best bound for Gaussian matrices is in: W. Xu and B. Hassibi, Precise Stability Phase Transitions for l1 Minimization: A Unified Geometric Framework, IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory. Oct. 2011

See, for example, the curves in Fig. 1.

Comment: Would please give out your understanding of the paper, in non-technical way, preferably?